# Windows software to find the narrowest/widest font available on a system

Tags: windows, gratis, user-interface, font-utility, font

I'm seeking recommendations for gratis Windows software that will identify the narrowest/widest fonts available on a system.

I'm fine if the fonts just need to be present as files, or if they need to be installed.  Either way is good.

At the least, it needs to be able to handle TrueType and OpenType fonts.

The software needs to make it clear which fonts are the narrowest or widest.  It can either:

1. Perform this calculation internally, and inform the user of the results.
2. Display text samples on the screen, and let the user decide.  If it does this, the software *must* be able to sort by width.  A list of 80 text samples (from 80 fonts) in alphabetic order will not be sufficient.

Ideally, the user can specify the sample text string, but any reasonable alphanumeric string will be sufficient.  Something like "ABCDEFGHIJKLabcdefghijkl012345" or "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog 0123456789" is fine.

Portable and open-source software are preferred, but neither is a hard requirement.

Comment: Interesting. +1 Never thought of this, but it could indeed be helpful